# Laravel Can't login the user after register

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication

**Laravel Can't log in the user after register**

When I register a new User, it returns successful, but when I try to log in it just returns 'login email id or password invalid'. I can't figure out what's wrong. It's working on the first created account, and it does not work for newly created accounts

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $user           =new Customer;
        $user->email     =$request->email;
        $user->password    =Hash::make($request->password);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $data['token'] = $user->createToken('kla')->accessToken;
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => true,
                'data'      => $data,
                'message'   => ''
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => false,
                'data'      => [],
                'message'   => 'login email id or password invalid'
            ]);
        }
    }
    public function register(Request $request){
        $user           =new Customer;
        $user->firstname     =$request->firstname;
        $user->lastname     =$request->lastname;
        $user->email     =$request->email;
        $user->password     =Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->country     =$request->country;
        $user->mobile     =$request->mobile;
        if($user->save()){
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => true,
                'data'      => [],
                'message'   => 'User Registation Successfully'
            ]);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => false,
                'data'      => [],
                'message'   => 'User Registation Faild'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is customer model

```
class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable ,HasApiTokens;
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'password',
        'country',
        'mobile',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

this is my Config/auth.php

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

         'Customers' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
             'table' => 'customers',
         ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is auth configured to use this `Customer` model?

Comment: @lagbox sorry I update it right now

Comment: did you configure auth to use this model instead of the default `User` model in `config/auth.php`? is that safe to assume that is the Session driver being used for what ever the default guard is currently or is that some JWT driver?

Comment: you can add the configuration to your question as we would need to see what the defaults are as well

Comment: @lagbox Okay, I changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your guards are setup to use this `Customer` model as none of them are using your `Customers` provider setup; which will be renamed to the lowercase version `customers` from here out. The 'provider' key for the guard would need to be `customers` in this case.

```
'guards' => [
    ...
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'customers',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    ...
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

Also when making calls to the authentication system it will use the default guard unless told otherwise. So without specifying you are currently using the `web` guard. If you wanted to use the 'passport' driver, that the `api` guard is set to use, you would have to adjust the default or specify this:

```
Auth::guard('api')->....
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config file you should define provider

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```